# Set up direction from right to left jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such a problem because I need to set the numbers in the html input to write from right to left. And I set it up with `jQ('[id="applying_credit"]').css('direction','rtl');` and it's working but when i try put some negative number like e.g "-2" its gives me "2-" . The minus sign goes to the end and I'd like it to go before 2 . Is there any chance to do it ?

https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/h2rn3b06/
`

```
              <div class="col col-1">
                        <input type="text" name="applying_credit" id="applying_credit" class="small" />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use text-align instead of direction

```
jQ('[id="applying_credit"]').css('text-align','right');
```